# Regex of an exact word with space in Java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

How to match an exact word containing a white space via Regex in Java ?

Ex., lets say I want to capture "- Mail (Raw)" which regex I need ?
I tried `.*[\-][\s]Mail[\s](Raw)` but it is failing.

Here are some sample Input and expected Output :

1. Hello - Mail (Raw) : true
2. Hello - mail (raw) : true
3. Hello mail rawed here : false
4. Hello -mail (raw): false
5. - Mail (Raw) : false
6. - Mail (raw) : false
7. - Mail (Raw) say hello : false
8. - Mail (raw) say Hi : false

Comment: `(` and `)` need to be escaped: `\(Raw\)`, or in a string literal: `"\\(Raw\\)"`

Comment: So you just need to match the literal string `- Mail (Raw)` but case insensitive?

Comment: Yeah.. But I really struggled with escaping and whitespaces.

Comment: Any reason for downvote? I made sure that the question is unique across SO... !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer. Regex I was looking for is :

```
.*\s-\s[Mm]ail\s\([Rr]aw\)
```

Meaning :

.* any characters

\s followed by space

- followed by hyphen

\s followed by space

[Mm]ail matching Mail or mail

\s followed by space

\( followed by open brace

[Rr]aw
   matching Raw or raw

\) followed by close brace

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "Hello - Mail (Raw)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\s+-\\s+(?<recepient>[Mm]ail\\s+\\([Rr]aw\\))");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

if (matcher.matches()) {
    String recepient = matcher.group("recepient");
}
```

***P.S.*** https://regex101.com/ is our friend